# Libreoffice 7.0 not displaying icons Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, ppa

I installed Libreoffice 7.0 using the official PPA on my Kubuntu 20.04 install. Mostly, things seem to work well. However, I have noticed that the icons in the top ribbon menu are not properly displayed, which makes it hard to see which command is which. Does any one have any potential solutions to get the icons back, or alternatively, what is the best way to uninstall and downgrade to the current supported LibreOffice version (6.whatever).

I've linked an image of what this looks like here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jup29.png)

Comment: I am not certain, but I'm pretty sure the fix is the same as it was [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/195345/62-icons-not-showing-correctly/).

Comment: I don't think an answer exists on AU. I'll go ahead and type one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is from [this site](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/195345/62-icons-not-showing-correctly/).

Open LibreOffice, click on 'Tools' and then 'Options.' This will open a new window, where you'll click on 'View' under the 'LibreOffice' heading. Once there, click on 'Icon style' and select the icons you'd like to use.

It looks like:

[image: libreoffice options]

Click 'Okay' and you should be all set.

Note: You may have different styles available *and* it's probably not black like mine is, as I use a system-wide theme.

Comment: Is Tango still available in Libreoffice 7? The release notes say it was removed

Comment: Good catch! Thanks! I have an older version of LibreOffice. I'll update my answer.